# Wondering why my last case in my switch statement is working properly

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

my switch statement works fine unless the match results in a tie and im not sure how to properly write the operation for it. I have tried several different approaches with no luck. At first I tried to use gameBoard.board[0]===("X"||"O") also with no luck. Any advice to pint me in the right direction will be very appreciated!

```
        switch(true){
            case gameBoard.board[0]==="X" && gameBoard.board[1]==="X" && gameBoard.board[2]==="X" :
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[0]==="X" && gameBoard.board[3]==="X" && gameBoard.board[6]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[0]==="X" && gameBoard.board[4]==="X" && gameBoard.board[8]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[1]==="X" && gameBoard.board[4]==="X" && gameBoard.board[7]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[2]==="X" && gameBoard.board[5]==="X" && gameBoard.board[8]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[3]==="X" && gameBoard.board[4]==="X" && gameBoard.board[5]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[6]==="X" && gameBoard.board[7]==="X" && gameBoard.board[8]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[6]==="X" && gameBoard.board[4]==="X" && gameBoard.board[2]==="X":
                alert("Player1 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[0]==="O" && gameBoard.board[1]==="O" && gameBoard.board[2]==="O" :
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[0]==="O" && gameBoard.board[3]==="O" && gameBoard.board[6]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[0]==="O" && gameBoard.board[4]==="O" && gameBoard.board[8]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[1]==="O" && gameBoard.board[4]==="O" && gameBoard.board[7]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[2]==="O" && gameBoard.board[5]==="O" && gameBoard.board[8]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[3]==="O" && gameBoard.board[4]==="O" && gameBoard.board[5]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[6]==="O" && gameBoard.board[7]==="O" && gameBoard.board[8]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[6]==="O" && gameBoard.board[4]==="O" && gameBoard.board[2]==="O":
                alert("Player2 Wins")
                break;
            case gameBoard.board[0]===("X"||"O") && gameBoard.board[1]===("X"||"O") && gameBoard.board[2]===("X"||"O") && 
                 gameBoard.board[3]===("X"||"O") && gameBoard.board[4]===("X"||"O") && gameBoard.board[5]===("X"||"O") &&
                 gameBoard.board[6]===("X"||"O") && gameBoard.board[7]===("X"||"O") && gameBoard.board[8]===("X"||"O"):
            alert("You Tied, No WInner")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You last case statement is true when any one of those `startsWith` is true ....

Comment: Can you show the entire switch statement?

Comment: @JaromandaX so basically my && operands are not doing what I want them to do :/. Im a newbie here any hints as to what the correct method will be?

Comment: @Khalil got it up, wasn't letting me at first for some reason

Comment: that whole statement is quite frankly not something I'd ever write - readability is key to good coding

Comment: Ok well good to know. Its up and running so thats the important part for me. If you dont mind could you tell me what approach you would've taken instead? I feel like an if/else would be just as confusing to read.

Comment: I would recommend a function that takes `X` or `O` as an argument. This function checks each possible win scenario i.e. `[0,1,2]` are all the player passed in, `[3,4,5]` `[6,7,8]`, `[0,3,6]` etc ... if it finds 3 in a row, it returns `true` to indicate a win, otherwise it returns false ... this function then can be called  twice, once for `X` and once for `O` ... now you've halved your code - only 8 case statements, and a default value of `false` - you don't even need to check all the weird and wonderful combinations since if the previous 8 cases are all false, the player did not win

Comment: Wow okok that makes a lot more sense hahah! Im going to see if I can get a function like that to work. Thanks so much, I still have a lot to learn but Im trying my best to think like a programmer.

Comment: one hint about switch ... `case a: case b: case c: code that runs for a, b or c case` - that alone will reduce the alerts from 17 to 3 - but in all honesty, you don't need to use switch/case at all for determining if a player has 3 in a row

Answer (score 1):

This part
`gameBoard.board[0]===("X"||"O")`
is not correct because you are evaluating the `("x" || "o")` part, then comparing that with the `gameBoard.board[0]` value.
`"X" || "O"` will always return "X" because it is truthy

So you are basically comparing this for the entirety of the last case statement

```
gameBoard.board[0]==="X" && gameBoard.board[1]==="X" && gameBoard.board[2]==="X" .....(and more)
```

To fix it, it should be

```
(gameBoard.board[0]==="X" || gameBoard.board[0]==="O") && (gameBoard.board[1]==="X" || gameBoard.board[1]==="O") &&
(gameBoard.board[2]==="X" || gameBoard.board[2]==="O") ......(and more)
```

Or just use a loop to check it...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This did it for me. Thanks so much for the explanation too! Thats the important part :)

Answer (score -1):

The alert and break isn't indented so it won't execute. Also, when using conditions such as && or || you should use an if statement. Generally speaking, it's an incorrect use of the switch statement from my understanding. Either way, I hope this helps :)

Comment: Ahh I was not aware of that! Also Thanks for reminding me about those indentations. Unfortunately they did not fix the bug :/

Comment: I think the problem is because it's an incorrect use of the switch statement. Reason being, you need to be SUPER specific and there's too many possibilities for a tie. What I'm going to suggest will be extremely tedious but seemingly the only fix. Convert the switch statement to an if/else if. That way at the end you can just put else at the end. Seems to be the only fix just because it's really difficult to be that specific

Comment: Don't post a comment as an answer